# adding styles to different part of an unordered list, wordpress widget

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

I think the best way to describe my problem is to show you.

http://yourinternship.hailstormcommerce.com/?page_id=21

On the sidebar on the left there is a widget that uses `ul`, a the moment I have a `bottom-border` applied to the first `li` and then the border turned off for any child `li` after that.

My issue is , the border for "Your Internship" at the very top of the widget doesnt appear until its submenu is finished, ie above "Accomodation". But I want it straight underneath "Your Internship" , like the rest of the menu pages. So basically its bordering the entire `li`. I understand why this is happening, and the only way I was able to get around it was by putting a border underneath `ul li a` but the problem is this ends up being very messy, for controlling the width of the border etc. (using `padding` etc).

Has anyone any suggestions on how I could apply a border to the first link?

Also, on the same note , is it possible to remove the last border under "Contact Us"?

Im asking the second question here as well as I guess my overall problem has to do with styling particular parts of a widget from wordpress.

Thanks in advance for any help. Any questions let me know, because I may have made that sound confusing.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. I made a simplified example that you can learn from:

```
<ul class="widget">
  <li class="active">Your Internship
    <ul>
      <li>Benefit of our program</li>
      <li>Students</li>
      <li>University</li>
      <li>Why Choose Us</li>
      <li>Your Internship Process</li>
      <li>Your Language Course</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Your Accomodation</li>
  <li>Your Employers</li>
  <li>Information for Interns</li>
  <li>Apply Now</li>
  <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

To get rid of the border on the active and last item use this pseudo selectors:

```
.widget > li:last-child, .active {
  border: none;
}
```

To re-add a border on the "`active`" class, I used a pseudo element:

```
.active:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid salmon;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/mbokL)

Comment: Thanks to you both, I used the first part of the first answer for the initial issue and for my second problem I used the second answer

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit messier than you want to, but here is a suggestion.

To get the line directly underneath "Your Internship" (but still keeping it above "Your Accomdation") you can do the following:

```
#menu-your-internship-sidebar .current_page_parent > a {
    display: block
    border-bottom: solid 1px #DDD;
 }
```

For removing the last border under "Contact Us" you just set the li:last-child bottom border to 0, like this:

```
#menu-your-internship-sidebar li:last-child {
    border: none
}
```

EDIT:
If you want to remove the border above "Your Accomdation":

```
#menu-your-internship-sidebar > li.current-page-parent {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you both, I used the first part of the first answer for the initial issue and for my second problem I used the second answer